# Will the table with composite primary keys supports group replication in innodb

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-group-replication

I have a table with two columns col1, col2 which are composite primary keys. Will, that table supports group replication in MySQL InnoDB clustering?

**Error message:**

> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate
>   flushing: Could not execute JDBC batch update; uncategorized
>   SQLException for SQL [/* insert collection row
>   com.domain.BatchClass.documentTypes */ insert into
>   batch_class_document_type (batch_class_id, document_type_id) values
>   (?, ?)]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [3098]; The table does not
>   comply with the requirements by an external plugin.; nested exception
>   is

**SHOW CREATE TABLE:**

```
CREATE TABLE `batch_class_document_type` (
    `batch_class_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
    `document_type_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`batch_class_id`,`document_type_id`), 
    KEY `FKB72AFCD2997AC796` (`document_type_id`), 
    KEY `FKB72AFCD2C473EFCA` (`batch_class_id`), 
    CONSTRAINT `FKB72AFCD2997AC796` FOREIGN KEY (`document_type_id`)
                 REFERENCES `document_type` (`id`), 
    CONSTRAINT `FKB72AFCD2C473EFCA` FOREIGN KEY (`batch_class_id`)
                 REFERENCES `batch_class` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: It would be mighty lame if it did not support such.

Comment: Actually, the above table is relational mapping table with many-to-many association which is created from hibernate(manyto many annotation). When doing that getting the error the table is not compatible for external plugin group replication.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the specific error message.

Comment: @RickJames, provided the requested artifacts.

Comment: Was there nothing after "nested exception is " ?

Comment: Please file a bug report at bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: The requirements are documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-replication-requirements.html and it says the table must have a PRIMARY KEY (or non-NULL UNIQUE KEY), but no mention of lack of support for composite PK. I didn't find a bug about this in bugs.mysql.com. Just several cases of the same error for tables that have no PK, or tables that are MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error when updating, not when creating the table right?

> insert into batch_class_document_type (batch_class_id, document_type_id) values (?, ?)

My guess is that you are running your group in multi primary mode and as stated here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-replication-deploying-in-multi-primary-or-single-primary-mode.html

> If a transaction executes against a table that has foreign keys with cascading constraints, then the transaction fails to commit when synchronizing itself with the group.

You are hitting this limitation. My suggestion is to try to run it in Single Primary mode.

Comment: I have created MySQL sandbox cluster with 3 nodes, 1 primary instance and 2 secondary instances. So, my current cluster is already in single primary mode.

Comment: I tested that table with the previous creation of simple document_type and batch_class tables with "id" keys. In my tests with 5.7.25 I can insert into the batch_class_document_type  table with no errors. So I assume maybe the issue is with the other tables? Add the table structure for them.